# Jboss drools throwing error Unable to Analyse Expression for boolean variable

Tags: java, drools

I have a very simple test case to reward the player if he registers the first time. When I am running my test case getting an error.

> Message [id=1, kieBase=defaultKieBase, level=ERROR, path=player.drl, line=10, column=0 
>      text=Unable to Analyse Expression isNew == true: 
>   [Error: no such identifier: isNew] 
>   [Near : {... isNew == true ....}] 
>                ^
>   [Line: 10, Column: 8]]

I checked that the model class has the variable declared correctly and the same is referred to .drl file.

**Player.drl**

```
import com.xyz.model.business.objects.Player;
import com.xyz.rules.domain.Points;
import java.util.*;

global com.xyz.rules.domain.Points points;
dialect  "mvel"

rule "Reward Point if User registered"
    when
        playerInstance:Player(isNew == true);
    then
        points.setPoints(1000);
end
```

**Model Class**

```java
package com.xyz.model.business.objects;    
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter
@Setter
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
public class Player {        
        private String userId;
        private String name;
        private int age;
        private boolean isNew;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [drools - Unable to Analyse Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18045403/drools-unable-to-analyse-expression)

Comment: @RLD given thread did not answer to my question. As you see it was case of getter/setter for the boolean property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should should implement [getters](https://www.codejava.net/coding/java-getter-and-setter-tutorial-from-basics-to-best-practices#NamingConvention) for the bean / model properties. As `new` is reserved word in Java I would replace it with `new_`. Because the property type is `boolean` getter name is `isNew_` not `getNew_`.

**Rule**

Replace `Player(isNew == true)` with `Player(new_ == true)`.

**Model**

Replace

```java
private boolean isNew;
```

with

```java
private boolean new_;
public boolean isNew_() {
    return new_;
}
```

Comment: Yeah!!! Since 'new' is reserved so isNew is getter. I believe it is conflicting. So changed it to _new :-)

Answer (score 2):

I see that methods are being generated by lombok and boolean method is coming like below

```js
public boolean isNew() {
    return isNew;
}

public void setNew(boolean aNew) {
    isNew = aNew;
}
```

but when I explicitly added get/set then drools understood it.

> getXXX() & setXXX()

So instead of auto-generated. I put get & set explicitly for boolean and **voila**

```js
   public boolean getIsNew() {
        return isNew;
    }

    public void setNew(boolean aNew) {
        isNew = aNew;
    }
```

Comment: I used Lombok just for constructors, but had to appeal to getters conventions too, as of lombok `@Data` or `@Getter` annotations didn't work. Aside note: it happens when using external DTOs (_import_), if you're using `declare` clause within a .drl, it recognizes correctly all these boolean properties.